# why summary on test model have to feed data into train model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I build a lstm model for training with summary on my loss. And I also build a test model with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse = True).

```
with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse=None):
    training_model = MyModel(...., feedforward_only = False)
with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse = True):
    test_model = MyModel(...., feedforward_only = True)
```

Now I'd like to view my loss on **test model**, so in my step() function, I add the self.merged into my output list:

```
if not forward_only:
    output_feed = [self.update,
            self.gradient_norm,
            self.loss,
            self.outputs,
            self.merged]
else:
    output_feed = [self.loss,
            self.outputs,
            self.merged]
```

When I feed data into training model, I successfully get the merged summary and view the loss on tensorboard.

**But when I try to feed data into the test model using step() function, it raised an error :**

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'model/inputs/sequence_length' with dtype int32 and shape [?]
```

I found out that, in fact, the variables created by get_variables() are shared with training model because they have the same name of 'model/variable_name'. But the rest variables including all the placeholders are using different names. In training model, they are 'model/variable_name' while in test model 'model_1/variable_name'.

So I think that, when I feed data into the test model, I actually feed into 'model_1/placeholder'. And I think there is no problem.

In fact there is indeed no problem to get the test results **if I do not add self.merged into my outputs list.**

When I add self.merged into the outputs list, however, I got the error message described above. It says that I must feed data into **model/place_holder.** instead of **model_1/placeholder** which is the place_holder of test model.

I wonder why I have to feed data into my training model when I want to feed data into my test model to get summary.

Or is there something wrong on my code?